# accessibilityLabel and testID props in 3rd party modules

Tags: react-native

I have come across a couple of react-native third party modules that don't pass on the props `accessibilityLabel` and `testID` to the underlying components e.g. `<Text />` and `<View />`. While it is completely up to the module author to implement this it makes it much harder to test apps using these components as test frameworks like *Appium* for example rely on these IDs to be set in order to be able to uniquely identify a component. (Okay there's XPath but that is not a great option)

How should this be addressed? I can think of the following options

- Let react-native handle it automatically
- Include a note in the docs to remind authors that this is important
- Have react-native display a warning if the props are not being passed on

Posting here since their Github page seems flooded and this doesn't need to be tracked as an issue yet. Would love to see some opinions.

Comment: Hi Did you resolve this issue?